# How to clean object files without using command 'make clean' when compiling with makefile?

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

What I want to know is how to write a makefile that compiles a program and then removes the object files created in the process with just using command 'make' so I don't have to run command 'make clean' afterwards. Here's my current makefile:

```
prog: prog.o prog_func.o
    gcc prog.o prog_func.o -o prog -Wall -std=c99   
prog.o: prog.c prog_func.h
    gcc prog.c -c -Wall -std=c99 
prog_func.o: prog_func.c prog_func.h
    gcc prog_func.c -c -Wall -std=c99
clean:
    rm prog.o prog_func.o
```

**EDIT:**

And this is how it's done:

```
prog: prog.o prog_func.o
    gcc prog.o prog_func.o -o prog -Wall -std=c99
    rm prog.o prog_func.o
prog.o: prog.c prog_func.h
    gcc prog.c -c -Wall -std=c99 
prog_func.o: prog_func.c prog_func.h
    gcc prog_func.c -c -Wall -std=c99
```

It works now. Thanks for quick responses.

Comment: That isn't exactly what a regular `clean` target does in the first place. It general destroys **all** contrived files including .o files *and* the final output target. I suspect you could always just remove the .o files after linking in the main target (though it wreaks of wonderment *why* you would want to do so).

Comment: This seems pretty useless to me.  The entire point of make is that it only rebuilds files that have changed.  That's why it has the extra syntax to declare prerequisites etc.  If you always delete all the files every time then everything is always rebuilt, and you might as well just write a little shell script that always recompiles everything every time, and don't bother with `make` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After building executable, you just give the same command (rm command) after the executable command

Answer (score 0):

How about compile without making f files like this

```
gcc -Wall -o prog prog.c
```

this command will not produce o files.

Answer (score -1):

I have just taken a sample example.

```
makebuild: clean prog                                
prog: 
    gcc a.c -o a.o
clean:
    rm a.o
```

Running 'make' from command line will first 'rm' a.o file and then run 'gcc a.c -o a.o'. The only problem here is that it will not work for first time as makebuild is calling clean first and it will throw an error as it will not find a.o file. You have to put check that 'rm' only when a.o file is present.

something like this:

```
clean:
    if a.o exist
        rm a.o
```

Comment: This is called `rm -f`.